# Find matches and fill array

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to build a filter function to make it easy for editor users to write html.

The users are going to input a text like this:

```
Fusce eget sapien a tortor hendrerit pharetra sed a libero. Vestibulum quis dui sed elit         semper semper non molestie nulla. Curabitur suscipit feugiat varius.

{{accordion}}
  {{title}}1 This is the first accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}1 This is the first accordion body{{body_end}}
  {{title}}1 This is the second accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}1 This is the second accordion body{{body_end}}
  {{title}}1 This is the third accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}1 This is the third accordion body{{body_end}}
{{accordion_end}}

Nulla consequat cursus turpis vitae pretium. Suspendisse iaculis nisl rhoncus justo luctus vel scelerisque diam volutpat.

{{accordion}}
  {{title}}2 This is the first accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}2 This is the first accordion body{{body_end}}
  {{title}}2 This is the second accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}2 This is the second accordion body{{body_end}}
  {{title}}2 This is the third accordion title{{title_end}}
  {{body}}2 This is the third accordion body{{body_end}}
{{accordion_end}}

Ut imperdiet odio quis diam ornare in congue purus rhoncus. Quisque scelerisque est sed sapien facilisis a facilisis turpis adipiscing. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
```

Note that the accordion blocks appears between other pieces of text, and they appear in multiple occurences.

I am using a template to theme the accordions, so I would like the accordions structured as an array, and then inject the themed accordions in the right positions in the text.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1 This is the first accordion title
            [body] => 1 This is the first accordion body
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1 This is the second accordion title
            [body] => 1 This is the second accordion body
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1 This is the third accordion title
            [body] => 1 This is the third accordion body
        )

)
```

I have been messing around with preg_replace_callback, but I cant really find the right way to do this.

So far Ive been doing like this:

```
function format_accordion($text) {

  $regex = '#{{accordion}}(.+?){{accordion_end}}#is';

  return preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    "lolfunction",
    $text);
}


function lolfunction($accordion_content) {

  $title_regex = '#{{title}}(.+?){{title_end}}#is';
  $body_regex = '#{{body}}(.+?){{body_end}}#is';

  $data = array();

  foreach ($accordion_content as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]['title'] = $key . " title"; // I need to find the titles
    $data[$key]['body'] = $key . " body"; // I need to find the bodies
  }



  return theme("kunsten_accordion", array("data" => $data));

}
```

The theme() function passes the array to a html template. I named the function lolfunction(), because I had hoped to have everything in just one function format_accordion() :)

Comment: Will it really be easier for your users to write `{{accordion}}{{title}}{{body}}` when they could use standard XML (or even HTML) to mark up the text? If you use XML (`<accordion><title><body>`) you won't need to write a custom parser.

Comment: I dont want them to write html, which would mean that they have to writes classes i.e. also. But perhaps its a good idea to have them write xml. I would still, however, have to replace the xml tags with html+classes. Any ideas?

Comment: yea except its the other way around. I have a string. Then turn matches into array. Then format array to a new string. And then inject the new string back into the original text.

Comment: @tolborg What PHP version are you using ? Since PHP 5.3 you can use anonymous functions which will get ride of "lolfunction".

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Yea I know, but I would have to write the entire thing as a string :S

Comment: @tolborg Then I don't understand it anymore, what would you like to do ? You have an input, that's fine, and then ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV. I have an input text. I want to find occurences of {{accordion}}. I want to convert content of occurences into array. I want to convert the array to html (I got that covered using theme()). Lastly I want to replace original {{accordion}} with my converted html.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I ended up doing this:

```
function format_accordion($text) {

  $regex = '#{{accordion}}(.+?){{accordion_end}}#is';

  return preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($content) {

      $title_regex = '#{{title}}(.+?){{title_end}}#is';
      $body_regex = '#{{body}}(.+?){{body_end}}#is';

      // find all titles
      preg_match_all($title_regex, $content[1], $titles);

      // find all bodies
      preg_match_all($body_regex, $content[1], $bodies);


      $data = array();

      foreach($titles[1] as $key => $title) {
        $data[$key]['title'] = $title;
      }
      foreach($bodies[1] as $key => $body) {
        $data[$key]['body'] = $body;
      }

      return theme("kunsten_accordion", array("data" => $data));
    },
    $text);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the most straightforward way I can think of :)